# MyBatis ошибка при запуске проекта

Tags: spring, mybatis

Программа для работы с БД использует mybatis.

Есть конфигурационный файл ApplicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">
    <!-- 1 -->
    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:schema.sql" />
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:test-data.sql" />
    </jdbc:embedded-database>
    <!-- 2 -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <!-- 3 -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.vit.service" />

    <!-- 4 Define the SqlSessionFactory -->
    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="com.vit.domain" />
    </bean>

    <!-- 5 Scan for mappers and let them be autowired -->
    <bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
        <property name="basePackage" value="com.vit.persistence" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

И метод который запускает программу

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
        ctx.load("classpath:ApplicationContext.xml");
        ctx.refresh();

        PersonService personService = ctx.getBean("personService", PersonService.class);
...
}
```

метод ругается на строку "ctx.load("classpath:ApplicationContext.xml");"

подскажите пожалуйста почему?

Comment: Что именно значит "ругается"?

Comment: Все понял, файл ApplicationContext.xml нужно было писать в папке с ресурсами. У меня был вне этой папки.